google signin in firebase flutter problem - Access blocked: authorisation error Storagerelay URI is not allowed for 'NATIVE_ANDROID'
i have tried to implement google signin feature in my flutter app using firebase and when i try to signin the pop up successfully pops but it tells Access blocked: authorisation error Storagerelay URI is not allowed for 'NATIVE_ANDROID' client type. If you are a developer of medicinal_plant_app, seetext

i have checked if there are dependency problems in the project files and used chatgpt to add solve the issues but everytime an error gets solved the next arrives and this one is really hard to solve

What does is shows when you click error details. Normally it will tell you do add browser origin or redirect api.
